Why environment variables are not encrypted in airflow?
I added fernet_key inside the airflow.cfg, but environment variables are not encrypted in  airflow admin?

Did you setup the Fernet key in the Airflow configuration file (airflow.cfg) under the [core] section ?
[core]
fernet_key = your_fernet_key
U need to restart Airflow after setting the Fernet key.
Obs:  Just new variables will be encrypted.
